# How to merge PDF files without external dependencies

Tags: pdf

In one of my applications I need to merge many single PDF documents into one document, where each of the original PDFs is a page. Although many PDF libraries exist for most languages, I would like to write this myself if it's not too hard.

Is it necessary to implement a full-fledged PDF parser in order to merge PDF documents? Where and what would I start to read to find out what is needed for the task?

Comment: *Is it necessary to implement a full-fledged PDF parser* - You indeed need to implement nearly a complete PDF parser. The better a merge you want, the more complete the parser need be. *Where and what would I start to read to find out what is needed for the task* - At least the PDF specification ISO 32000-1, a copy made available [here](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) by Adobe.

Comment: Thank you, I feared that this is necessary. 
With regards to the downvoting: I don't think the question is posed unclearly or too broad. The answer of mkl is very short but precise and is exactly what I was asking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Debenu QuickPDF Library Lite (free) version to do it. Here is a very good example how to do it:

http://www.debenu.com/kb/merge-pdf-files-together-programmatically/